# Service Discovery between different aws accounts eks clusters

Tags: networking, amazon-eks, istio, service-discovery

Can anybody help in suggesting some ways for below scenario:

we have 2 aws accounts and each aws account has 1 eks cluster running. We have a requirement where we have to establish service discovery between both the clusters where one cluster can call another cluster service privately. so we need to establish communication between both the eks clusters via some global service mesh. any ideas how can this be achieved in best posssible way?

Comment: hi Jay, were you able to find an approach for this? I am looking to do the same.